# How to extend Clang with an additional parser?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

How can I extend Clang with an additional parser for files with a special file ending, i.e. can I develop a `FrontendAction` that says "Hey! I'll take care of all files with the file ending '.lorem' and return an abstract syntax tree (`clang::ASTContext` ?)"?

I've read about `clang::FrontendAction`, `clang::Parser` and `clang::driver::Driver` but I haven't been able to figure out where and how I should extend Clang to be able to extend the compiler with an additional parser (*not* extending the current parser).

Comment: Is your extended language similar to C/C++/Objective-C? Clang is the frontend for these kinds of languages. If we want to reuse the backend (optimization, etc.), we only need LLVM.

Comment: The language will be similar to Objective-C++ (the semantics, not the syntax). The preprocessor is the same.

Comment: I dont know much about Clang. But how about transcompiling to ObjC then?

Comment: I want to get some benefits from using Clang - code completion integration, compiling C/C++/ObjC++ code at the same time, not having to generate code (just parsing and generating a high level AST), etc. Transcompiling to ObjC++ is possible, but then I would also have to be able to parse C/C++/ObjC/ObjC++ (in order to calculate which symbols are referenced) since I want to be able to reference/include files from C etc.

Comment: Did you get any information on this? Did you find that it was better to use LLVM directly, or were you able to generate an AST for Clang?

Comment: Hi @finnsson, I've come across the same set of questions. Were you able to figure out how to use a custom parser to generate an AST and process it via the res of Clang's Driver?

Comment: Clang's CFE Internals Manual is a great resource for understanding how to add statements/expressions: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#how-to-add-an-expression-or-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

in `tools/clang/lib/Driver/Types.cpp` you have `lookupTypeForExtension`, that determines the "type" of the compiled code based on the extension. For example, for the `.m` extension it returns `TY_ObjC`. You also have the `isObjC` predicate that determines whether the given type belongs to Objective C.

As for how the parser knows which language it's parsing... It knows it via the `Preprocessor`, which has a `LangOptions` member. The latter has many options defined in `include/clang/Basic/LangOptions.def`. For instance, `ObjC1` and `ObjC2`. These are set in `CompilerInvocation::setLangDefaults`, which eventually gets invoked from `CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs`.

Remember that the clang driver will invoke the clang frontend as a "subprocess", passing it additional command-line arguments. The driver is gcc-compatible, and the frontend can be seen as clang itself.

Also, IMHO it would be tons of trouble adding an extra parser to clang. While everything is modular, a lot of work needs to be done to create and tie everything together. If your language extends ObjC, just use the existing parser. If you language is something completely different, then clang may not be a good option for you.

Comment: Eli, have there been any updates to Clang's architecture since the time of your response that would make it easier to add an extra parser to Clang? Alternatively, is it possible to use a custom parser to create a `clang::TranslationUnitDecl` and process that AST through the rest of the Clang driver? Thanks!

Comment: @StefanNovak: I'll admit I don't know - it's been years since I worked with Clang intensively.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the quick response. I'm a big fan of your blog! :)